# Count duplicate values in a column, filter the results as unique values then sort largest to smallest

Tags: excel, excel-formula, duplicates

I have a large list of brands that includes dozens of duplicates for each value.  I would like to count how many times each value appears in the column, then to sort the count results largest to smallest & then to finally display the results (both the value and its count) as unique values, for example;

I would like this:

```
Nyke
adodis
Redbook
Nyke
Nyke
Redbook
Nyke
```

To become this:

```
Nyke (4)
Redbook (2)
adodis (1)
```

I understand that this can be done using sort & filter, pivot tables etc. as well as using the COUNTIF formula but would like to know if it is possible to achieve all steps using just formulas?

Thanks!

Comment: Use a Pivot Table

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "remove duplicates" on a copy of the data, then use "COUNTIF" to get the count from the original column, then give each row a number from "RANK.EQ" then finally sort the new table.